# firebase observeEventType for data change from children for which user may not have access to all children

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to write chat functionality using firebase. the data structure would be similar to this:
https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/data

It's unclear to me that if I want to observer for new messages added to any of the rooms under data/messages/{room_id}, is it possible to call Firebase.observeEventType on just "data/messages" if I have security rules user can only read messages for rooms he is in.
Or do I need to call observeEventType repeatedly for each data/messages/{room_id} for which he has access to.

Comment: What you need to do, depends on what you want to accomplish. If you're trying to write a chat application, the user is going to be in one chat room at a time. So in that case, you'd register a listener for that room only.

Comment: Firebase security rules are not filters. So if you listen to a node, but the user doesn't have access to *all* child nodes, you will get an error. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the comment. yeah, that's what I read in the doc as well. I wish it works like a filter. :)
I want to listen to all chats that the user is in so that when any of the chats has new messages, I can update the UI by changing the icon to indicate that there's unread messages. Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

Comment: You'd have to traverse every chat the user is in and keep an active listener.  But always consider if you really want that many active listeners. Alternatively consider if you shouldn't maybe denormalize your data. So for every user, keep a list of chats he's in and *update that when you add a new message*. That way the writes become more expensive, but your reads are dead cheap.

Comment: thanks. I'll give  your second suggestion a try.